# Creating CSV file generates corrupted data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv

I have the ff. code that creates CSV file. I used SpreadsheetLight library for this and it works great if opened through MS Excel but through text editor, it looks like the text is encrypted or corrupted. I figured this is an encoding problem but I am not sure what's missing or should be corrected on my code.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
SLDocument slDoc = new SLDocument();

slDoc.RenameWorksheet(SLDocument.DefaultFirstSheetName, detailList.exam_module_value);
slDoc.SetCellValue(1, 1, "[Question#]");
slDoc.SetCellValue(1, 2, "[Question]");
slDoc.SetCellValue(1, 3, "[Letter Choices]");
slDoc.SetCellValue(1, 4, "[Choices]");
slDoc.SetCellValue(1, 5, "[Tagging Correct Answer]");

int questionCnt = 1;

foreach (var q in detailList.ExamQuestions)
{
   char ltr = 'a';

   slDoc.SetCellValue(rowCtr, 1, questionCnt++);
   slDoc.SetCellValue(rowCtr, 2, q.question);

   foreach (var c in detailList.ExamChoices.Where(x => x.question_id == q.question_id).OrderBy(x => x.orderNo))
   {
       slDoc.SetCellValue(rowCtr, 3, ltr.ToString());
       slDoc.SetCellValue(rowCtr, 4, c.choice);
       slDoc.SetCellValue(rowCtr, 5, c.answer_state ? 1 : 0);

       ltr++;
       rowCtr++;
   }
}

slDoc.SaveAs(ms);
ms.Position = 0;

FileStreamResult file = new FileStreamResult(ms, "text/csv")
{
    FileDownloadName = string.Concat(detailList.exam_module_value, ".csv")
};

using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath(string.Concat(examPath, "/", detailList.exam_module_value, ".csv"))))
{      
     file.FileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     file.FileStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
     file.FileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //reset position to beginning. If there's any chance the FileResult will be used by a future method, this will ensure it gets left in a usable state
}

ms.Close();
```

[image: Excel]

[image: Text editor]

Comment: while you may have named it `.csv` the image shows the content of an actual xlsx OpenXml package file. which is why excel can process it with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CSVhelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to create csv files.

The one you use is for creating excel files. Even though I would consider free opensource crossplatform [openxml sdk](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK). Spreadsheet light works on top of it and haven't updated since 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You’re creating an excel document, not a CSV it looks like.

Try renaming the extension to .xls, or .xlsx.